# Word.Application ComObject on Powershell Cannot Open File from SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell script to update a Word document's content in the SharePoint Online Document Library.

Below is the script so far. The issue is the **$document** variable value is null when trying to get the file from SharePoint.

I've debugged the **$documentLocation**. The value is valid and the correct location of the file.
Also, I've tried to change the **$documentLocation** with a file located in a public site (not SharePoint). The result is **$document** value is not null.

Are there any missing steps in my script below?

```
add-type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word"
$save = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.wdSaveChanges" -as [type]
$application = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
$application.Visible = $false

$url = "https://{tenant}.sharepoint.com"

Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Credentials (Get-Credential)

$library = Get-PnPList | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq "Documents"}
$items = Get-PnPListItem -List $library
foreach ($item in $items) {
  if ($item["FileLeafRef"] -match ".doc*") {
    Write-Host "File Name: "$item["FileLeafRef"]  
    $documentLocation = -join ($url, $item["FileRef"])
    $document = $application.Documents.Open($documentLocation)

    # TODO: Update content

    $document.save()
    $document.close([Ref]$save)
    $item.File.Update()
  }
}

$application.quit()
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Answer (score 0):

Why edit the content? Just replace whole document every metadata will remain and no new version will be created. But here is -Stream so you can try update with this cmd not just replacing.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps)

[Great Example](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/upload-document-to-sharepoint-library-using-pnp-powershell)

Comment: Because I need to replace some particular words from the content. Is it possible to do that with Add-PnPFile?

Comment: Yes it should be possible, but I havent time to test it, so you can try it

Comment: How can I get the content to be upload?
Should I download the file > open the file in local > update the file > upload the file to SharePoint?
I want to replace some words only from the **footer** of **Word** document.